# Add 6 months to a date starting february

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to subtract 3 months from February to a date using lubridate library, however, it always gives me date as 28. I know a lot of people have asked this question, but I have tried a lot of things, but still the same error. Looping through the day is an option. However, I was looking for something efficient

what my code does is this:

where test_end = "2019-02-28"
and lastnmonth = 3

`as.Date(test_end) %m-% months(lastnmonth)`

I always get the output as "2018-11-28" instead of "2018-11-30"

Comment: That's 3 months, not 6. You can edit the question.

Comment: Corrected. Either of the months, the date is produced as 28. Would you happen to know the solution?

Comment: No, was just passing by. No idea about r or lubridate but, applying common sense, it all depends on what is considered "a month" in given context. You probably need to search for detaled info on months() function(?) that you use. And your first sentence is still misleading - do you get 28 regardless of the date you subtract from? I don't think so.

Comment: I mention, it's from February. So either 28 or 29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lubridate::ymd("2019-02-28") - lubridate::period(3, "months")
```

additional code to work-out mont-end

```
lubridate::ceiling_date(lubridate::ymd("2019-02-28") - lubridate::period(3, "months"), "months") - lubridate::ddays(1)
```

Comment: I tried, doesn't work. Also, I am working on Windows and not mac (Just FYI)

Comment: So it has no way to know `28Feb` is a month end, so naturally it takes you back 3 months falling on the current date. If you want to calibrate to end of month  then you need to tell the machine as such. I have provided additional code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You want the last of the month -- so you can use the trick that the *next* is a first, move that one by the number of months -- and then substract one day.

All in one line of base R:

```
R> seq(as.Date("2019-02-28") + 1, length=4, by="-1 month") - 1
[1] "2019-02-28" "2019-01-31" "2018-12-31" "2018-11-30"
R>
```

We add one day, then use a sequence of four months (including current) backwards, and take out one day to be on the last day of the previous month.

If you just want one, simply add `tail(..., 1)`:

```
R> tail(seq(as.Date("2019-02-28") + 1, length=4, by="-1 month") - 1, 1)
[1] "2018-11-30"
R>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Dirk's strategy we can draw-up a function to handle this type of operation:

```
start_date       <- lubridate::ymd("2019-02-28")
mths_to_subtract <- 3


deduct_mth <- function(date_object = start_date, 
                       mths_to_deduct = mths_to_subtract){

  days_to_ceiling_date <- lubridate::ceiling_date(date_object, "months") - date_object

  date_object + days_to_ceiling_date - lubridate::period(mths_to_deduct, "months") - days_to_ceiling_date

}
```

Gives the following answers:

```
> deduct_mth(ymd("2019-02-28"), 3)
[1] "2018-11-30"
> deduct_mth(ymd("2000-02-29"), 3)
[1] "1999-11-30"
```